# mysql query takes more than 1 day

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

mysql query takes more than 1 day, how to speet it up :

```
update posts set  category_id = (
    SELECT keyword_id 
    FROM post_keywords 
    where  keyword_id IN (
        SELECT  keyword_id  
        FROM post_keywords 
        where  id_post = posts.id_post)  
    group by keyword_id 
    order by count(keyword_id) DESC 
    limit 0,1
);
```

any solution ?

Comment: explain plan - break out all the smaller selects and test separately - add indexes

Comment: How many rows table post_keywords count?

Comment: Do you have index on keyword_id and id_post?

Comment: yes I have indexes on keyword_id and id_post

Comment: @sdespont about 200K records

Comment: And how many rows for tables posts and post_keywords?

Comment: It is not many rows. Try @Randy's advice.

Comment: @sdespont is there any other way to rewrite this query because already these columns had indexes and I need to run this query for many databases , some databases are too big

Comment: @b__ it's not wordpress

Comment: Main question is IMHO if you really need to run this for all posts every day ? I'm guessing that after a while the spread of the keywords will be more or less fixed thus 'old' posts won't change category very often. Simply apply it to all 'new' posts; let the old ones alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely the same thing, yet the outcome will still be what you want it to be I think. I'm mostly curious to how (IF!?) this might affect the performance.

```
UPDATE posts 
   SET category_id = (
                        SELECT pkw.keyword_id
                          FROM post_keywords pkw
                          JOIN (
                                    SELECT keyword_id, cnt = COUNT(*)
                                      FROM post_keywords 
                                     GROUP BY keyword_id ) cnts
                            ON cnts.keyword_id = pkw.keyword_id
                         WHERE pkw.id_post = posts.id_post
                         ORDER BY cnt DESC 
                         LIMIT 0,1

                    )
```

Comment: Well, I guess it only has to do the aggregation once now. I had no idea how mysql would handle this but it seems to work out as expected. Anyway, don't forget to close the question if you think this solves your problem. Good luck.